# Notify many controllers, when single service load data

Tags: angularjs

Scenario:
I have two controllers, which use one service, first controller could invoke search method, and get results when service loads data, second could only be notifyed that service load data.

Here my code :

```
app.factory "searchService", ($resource, $q, $log) ->
  resource = $resource("//localhost:8001/data/search/1")

  searchSuccessDef = $q.defer()

  searchSuccess: searchSuccessDef.promise

  search: (scope, term) ->
    def = $q.defer()

    resource.get(

    ((content) ->
      $log.info content
      searchSuccessDef.notify()
      def.resolve(content)
    ),

    ((response) ->
      $log.warn response
      def.reject(response)
    )
  )

  def.promise

  ///

app.controller "navpanelController", ($scope, searchService) ->

  $scope.search = (term) ->

   searchResult = searchService.search(term)

   searchResult.then (res) ->

    console.log "!!!"

    $scope.result = res

 ///

app.controller "contentController", ($scope, $q, searchService) ->

 searchService.searchSuccess.then (content) ->
  console.log "---"
```

But this doesn't work since `searchSuccessDef.notify()` not invoke notifyer  `searchService.searchSuccess.then (content) ->` , though if instead I use `searchSuccessDef.resolve()`, this fire the promise once.

That's the problem could be here. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not conversant with CoffeesSript, but what i can tell you is that the notify method callback is the 3rd argument to the `then` method

```
.then(function(greeting) {   //Success
   alert('Success: ' + greeting);
 }, function(reason) {      //Failure
   alert('Failed: ' + reason);
 }, function(update) {      //notification
   alert('Got notification: ' + update);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, feel myself arrgh, 2 hours spent, this coffee by the way :)